# Compress photo and put to another directory with tinify and python

Tags: python

I'm slowly starting to study about python and wanted to write simple script which use tinify api, takes photos from unoptimalized directiory, compress it and put to optimalized directory. So far works partly, I mean weirdly I need to keep photos in main directory and unoptimalized one. If I dont have another copy in one of these directories, I have error. another thing is that after I launch script, only first photo is compressed and put inside optimalized directory, and then error appears. 
So far I'm experimenting on two photos: lew.jpg and kot.jpg
My directory structure is like this:

Main root directory with script, and two other directories inside (optimalized and unoptimalized)

```
def optimalizeImages():
    for fname in os.listdir('./unoptimalized'):
        if fname.endswith(".jpg"):
            print(fname)
            source = tinify.from_file(fname)
            print("processing", fname)
            os.chdir("./optimalized")
            source.to_file("optimalized-" + fname)
            print("changed", fname)

optimalizeImages()
```

Error after processing first image:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 20, in <module>
    optimalizeImages()
  File "python.py", line 11, in optimalizeImages
    source = tinify.from_file(fname)
  File "/home/grzymowiczma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinify/__init__.py", line 79, in from_file
    return Source.from_file(path)
  File "/home/grzymowiczma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinify/source.py", line 13, in from_file
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kot.jpg'
```

and if i keep photos only in root directory, no error but also no any action, if i keep them only in unoptimalized i get same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 20, in <module>
    optimalizeImages()
  File "python.py", line 11, in optimalizeImages
    source = tinify.from_file(fname)
  File "/home/grzymowiczma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinify/__init__.py", line 79, in from_file
    return Source.from_file(path)
  File "/home/grzymowiczma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinify/source.py", line 13, in from_file
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lew.jpg'
```

Comment: *What* error appears? Please give us the full traceback for the exception, so we have the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here, both because you are using relative filenames. `os.listdir()` gives you those relative filenames, without a path. Instead of `./unoptimalized/kot.jpg`, you get just `kot.jpg`.

So when you try to load the image:

```
source = tinify.from_file(fname)
```

you tell the library to load `image.jpg` *without any context* other than the *current working directory*. And that's not the right directory, not if `os.listdir('./unoptimalized')` worked to list all image files; that indicates that the current working directory is in the parent directory of both `unoptimalized` and `optimalized`.

You solved that by putting an image file with the same name in the parent directory, but that's not quite the right way to solve this. More on this below.

The next issue is that you *change* the working directory:

```
os.chdir("./optimalized")
```

You do this for the first image, so now the current working directory has changed to `optimalized`. When you then loop back up for the next file, you are now in the wrong location altogether to read the next file. Now `lew.jpg`, which might exist in `./unoptimalized` or the parent directory, can't be found because it is not there in `./optimalized`.

The solution is to *add on* the directory name. You can do so with [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), and *not* changing directories:

```
def optimalizeImages():
    input_dir = './unoptimalized'
    output_dir = './optimalized'
    for fname in os.listdir(input_dir):
        if fname.endswith(".jpg"):
            print(fname)
            source = tinify.from_file(os.path.join(input_dir, fname))
            print("processing", fname)
            source.to_file(os.path.join(output_dir, "optimalized-" + fname))
            print("changed", fname)
```

Note that this still depends heavily on the current working directory being correct, but at least it is now stable and stays at the parent directory of both `optimalized` and `unoptimalized`. You may want to change that to using absolute paths.

And a side note on language: In English, the correct spelling of the two terms is *optimized* and *unoptimized*. I didn't correct those in my answer to keep the focus on what is going wrong.

Comment: Ah I had impression that loop is taking me to optimized directory but not getting back but wasn't really sure how does it work and how to fix it. Your answer is clear and shows me that I gotta focus a bit at paths and os commands about directories Thank you for explanation and wonderful answer! Everything works and I what's more important, I understand why! Thanks, also for correcting my spelling:)